# Problem with encoding of Polish characters in the database

Tags: php, sql, polish

my problem is that when I open a page on a localhost in xampp, it works fine, everything displays fine, but after uploading it to the server including the exported database, it does not correctly display Polish characters downloaded from the database. Of course, in the head section I added 'charset = UFT-8' metadata, and in the database both before exporting and importing in phpmyadmin I set utf8_polish_ci. When I enter data via a form on the page, the data in the database is also displayed incorrectly. Has anyone had a similar case and knows how to solve it? I am a beginner, and I only have basic knowledge, but with the website code itself, everything should be fine because, as I mentioned above, everything works for localhost.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5GIR.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEjjt.png)

Comment: `'charset = UFT-8'` ? probably: `'charset = UTF-8'`

Comment: Of course it's UTF-8 :), my fault in question

Comment: Thanks nbk, that solved my problem :)